# WordPress media library with metadata limit

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a media library window. attachment should filter with mime types and metadata.
the mime-type filter is done. How can I build a metadata filter just for this?

```js
function upload_image_tinymce(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $input_field = $('.mce-my_input_image');
    var custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Add Video',
        button: {
            text: 'Add Video'
        },
        library: {
            type: [
                'video/MP4',
                'video/quicktime',
                'video/x-m4v',
            ],
        },
        multiple: false
    });
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $input_field.val(attachment.id);
    });
    custom_uploader.open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant help you with the whole filter code (not enoth knowlage ...)
But you can use the hook wp_get_attachment_metadata('attachment id') to get an array with the whole metadata of the attachment.

```
$meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata(126);
```

Will produce an array with the metadata from the attachment 126.

```
$cam = $meta[camera]
```

$cam will then hold the camera string from the metadata ...

Not much but maybe it will lead you a little bit in the right direction.

Comment: thanks but it isn't relevant to the question.